# UIAlertController error

Tags: swift

I call below code from my add bar button item where I present alert view asking for user input. It works fine for the first time and give following error there after:

Code:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Blog Link", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    func userBlogLinkEntryPopover() {
        //        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Enter Blog Link", message: nil, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Blog URL!"
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if let tf = self.alert.textFields?.first as? UITextField{
                println(tf.text)
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

> Error : 'UIAlertController can only have one action with a style of
>   UIAlertActionStyleCancel'

I think it is trying to add action every time when add button is pressed and hence the error. Please correct me if I am wrong and also please suggest the work around.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why did you move `var alert` declaration out of the function `userBlogLinkEntryPopover`? Put it back in there. An alert doesn't need to be a property.

Answer (score 13):

you also get this if you do this, read carefully see if you can see the mistake

```
    resendAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        //cancel clicked
        return
    }))

    resendAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Check Server", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        //check server clicked
        return
    }))
```

NOTE---> the `.cancel` is **not** to be used TWICE it needs to be `.default` on the second one

```
    resendAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Check Server", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        //check server clicked
        return
    }))
```

works fine

Answer (score 3):

I found out that because alert was declared outside the function it retained all the actions and because of which it raised exception. I corrected my code as below and it worked fine.

```
 func userBlogLinkEntryPopover() {       
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Blog Link", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter Blog URL!"
        }
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if let tf = alert.textFields?.first as? UITextField{
                println(tf.text)
            }
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Regards

Comment: I had this exact problem. Behavior was strange until I put the variable in the same scope like you did. You should definitely make this the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what tripped me up - an autofill mistake.  Using ObjC, instead of using style UIAlertActionStyleDefault on an action, I used UIAlertControllerStyleAlert constant.  No warning, but both of these resolve to an enumeration value of 1, thus I had inadvertently added two Cancel actions to the same controller.